# Why does passing a dictionary as a parameter take more time?

Tags: python, dictionary

I tried to a leetcode problem. I find one of the following code throws a time limit exceeded error. I created the following testing code. I found the first one pass dictionary as a parameter takes more time the the other one. 0.94s vs 0.84s.
Can anyone explain this ?

```
class Solution(object):
    def longestPalindromeSubseq(self, x):
        """
        :type s: str
        :rtype: int
        """

        #dic = {}

        def helper(s, dic):
            if len(s) == 0:
                return 0
            if len(s) == 1:
                return 1

            if s in dic:
                return dic[s]

            if s[0] == s[-1]:
                res = helper(s[1:-1], dic)+2
            else:
                l1 = helper(s[:-1], dic)
                l2 = helper(s[1:], dic)
                res = max(l1,l2)
            dic[s] = res
            #print (id(dic), dic)  
            return res
        d = {}
        ans = helper(x, d)
        #print (id(d), d)
        return ans

class Solution1(object):
    def longestPalindromeSubseq(self, x):
        """
        :type s: str
        :rtype: int
        """

        dic = {}

        def helper(s):
            if len(s) == 0:
                return 0
            if len(s) == 1:
                return 1

            if s in dic:
                return dic[s]

            if s[0] == s[-1]:
                res = helper(s[1:-1])+2
            else:
                l1 = helper(s[:-1])
                l2 = helper(s[1:])
                res = max(l1,l2)
            dic[s] = res
            #print (id(dic), dic)
            return res
        ans = helper(x)
        #print (id(dic), dic)
        return ans

import time
if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = "gphyvqruxjmwhonjjrgumxjhfyupajxbjgthzdvrdqmdouuukeaxhjumkmmhdglqrrohydrmbvtuwstgkobyzjjtdtjroqpyusfsbjlusekghtfbdctvgmqzeybnwzlhdnhwzptgkzmujfldoiejmvxnorvbiubfflygrkedyirienybosqzrkbpcfidvkkafftgzwrcitqizelhfsruwmtrgaocjcyxdkovtdennrkmxwpdsxpxuarhgusizmwakrmhdwcgvfljhzcskclgrvvbrkesojyhofwqiwhiupujmkcvlywjtmbncurxxmpdskupyvvweuhbsnanzfioirecfxvmgcpwrpmbhmkdtckhvbxnsbcifhqwjjczfokovpqyjmbywtpaqcfjowxnmtirdsfeujyogbzjnjcmqyzciwjqxxgrxblvqbutqittroqadqlsdzihngpfpjovbkpeveidjpfjktavvwurqrgqdomiibfgqxwybcyovysydxyyymmiuwovnevzsjisdwgkcbsookbarezbhnwyqthcvzyodbcwjptvigcphawzxouixhbpezzirbhvomqhxkfdbokblqmrhhioyqubpyqhjrnwhjxsrodtblqxkhezubprqftrqcyrzwywqrgockioqdmzuqjkpmsyohtlcnesbgzqhkalwixfcgyeqdzhnnlzawrdgskurcxfbekbspupbduxqxjeczpmdvssikbivjhinaopbabrmvscthvoqqbkgekcgyrelxkwoawpbrcbszelnxlyikbulgmlwyffurimlfxurjsbzgddxbgqpcdsuutfiivjbyqzhprdqhahpgenjkbiukurvdwapuewrbehczrtswubthodv"
    print (x)
    t0 = time.time()
    sol = Solution()
    print (sol.longestPalindromeSubseq(x))
    t1 = time.time()
    print(t1- t0)

    sol1 = Solution1()
    print (sol1.longestPalindromeSubseq(x))
    t2 = time.time()
    print(t2-t1)
```

Comment: Passing a parameter takes more time than not passing a parameter. It doesn't really matter much what type it is. And since you're passing the parameter in all the recursive calls, it gets multiplied.

Answer (score 0):

Python uses something that is called *call by sharing*. The function gets only the alias on the parameter. With that in mind, it does't matter what you pass to the function.

But the script may take different time to execute. It is not constant. Using recursion makes it even harder to predict